# Problems in managing Memory-leaks C++

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I'm not getting any errors or something like this, but the problem is that no matter what I do, I can't get rid of those memory-leaks. The only solution that i found that helps me is to add `delete[] vector1` after every method but I'm not allowed to modify that part of the code.
In the code you can see the comments and the areas where I can add new instructions. Is there any solution to my problem?

THIS IS THE CODE:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

/*YOU CAN'T ADD NEW METHODS*/
/*YOU CAN ONLY MODIFY THE BODY OF THE METHODS*/

//read array from the console - number of elements and the elements
int * readVectorVersion1(int * noElements) {
    int *vector1;
    vector1 = new int[*noElements + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < *noElements; i++)
    {
        cout << endl << "Vector1[" << i + 1 << "]=";
        cin >> vector1[i];

    }
    return vector1;
}
//read array from the console - number of elements and the elements
void readVectorVersion2(int ** vector, int* noElements) {
    *vector = new int[*noElements + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < *noElements; i++)
    {
        cout << endl << "Vector1[" << i + 1 << "]=";
        cin >> (*vector)[i];
    }
}
//read array from the console - number of elements and the elements
void readVectorVersion3(int *& vector, int& noElements) {
    vector = new int[noElements + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < noElements; i++)
    {
        cout << endl << "Vector1[" << i + 1 << "]=";
        cin >> vector[i];
    }
}

//read array from the console - number of elements and the elements
int * readVectorVersion4(int& noElements) {
    int *vector1;
    vector1 = new int[noElements + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < noElements; i++)
    {
        cout << endl << "Vector1[" << i + 1 << "]=";
        cin >> vector1[i];
    }
    return vector1;
}

//read static array from the console - number of elements and the elements
void readStaticVector(int vector[], int * noElements) {
    for (int i = 0; i < *noElements; i++)
    {
        cout << endl << "Vector1[" << i + 1 << "]=";
        cin >> vector[i];
    }
}

//print the elements of the array
void afisareVector(int* vector, int noElements) {
    cout << endl << "Vector:" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < noElements; i++)
        cout << vector[i] << " ";

}


//read a name from the console
char* citesteNume() {
    char temp[200];
    char * nume;
    cout << endl << "Your name:";
    cin >> temp;
    nume = new char[strlen(temp) + 1];
    strcpy(nume, temp);

    return nume;
}

//read a name from the console
void citesteNume(char* nume) {


    cout << endl << "Your name:";
    cin >> nume;


}
//METHODS THAT ADDS AN ELEMENT (THAT IS GIVEN) TO AN EXISTING ARRAY
//FIRST
void adaugaElementNou(int** vector, int* noElemente, int elementNou) {
    (*vector) = new int[*noElemente + 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < *noElemente; i++)
        (*vector)[i] = i;

    (*vector)[*noElemente] = elementNou;

}
//SECOND
int * adaugaElementNou(int& noElemente, int elementNou) {
    int *vector;
    vector = new int[noElemente + 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < noElemente; i++)
        vector[i] = i;
    vector[noElemente] = elementNou;
    return vector;

}
//THIRD
int * adaugaElementNou(int* noElemente, int elementNou) {
    int *vector;
    vector = new int[(*noElemente) + 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < *noElemente; i++)
        vector[i] = i;
    vector[*noElemente] = elementNou;
    return vector;

}



//THE PROGRAM MUST RUN AND NOT GENERATE ANY ERRORS OR MEMORY-LEAKS
void main() {
    //YOU CAN'T ADD NEW VARIABLES

    int * vector1;
    int vector2[50];
    int nrElementeVector1=3;
    int nrElementeVector2=3;

    //YOU CAN ADD NEW INSTRUCTIONS
    // ...
    vector1 = new int[nrElementeVector1 + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < nrElementeVector1; i++)
        vector1[i] = i;
    for (int i = 0; i < nrElementeVector2; i++)
        vector2[i] = i;
    //YOU CAN'T MODIFY THE FOLLOWING CODE

    afisareVector(vector1, nrElementeVector1);
    afisareVector(vector2, nrElementeVector2);
    //delete[]vector1; /*This instruction is added by me but i`m not allowed to modify this area of the code*/
    vector1 = readVectorVersion1(&nrElementeVector1);
    afisareVector(vector1, nrElementeVector1);
    //delete[]vector1;
    readVectorVersion2(&vector1, &nrElementeVector1);
    afisareVector(vector1, nrElementeVector1);
    //delete[]vector1;
    readVectorVersion3(vector1, nrElementeVector1);
    afisareVector(vector1, nrElementeVector1);
    //delete[]vector1;
    vector1 = readVectorVersion4(nrElementeVector1);
    afisareVector(vector1, nrElementeVector1);
    //delete[]vector1;
    readStaticVector(vector2, &nrElementeVector2);
    afisareVector(vector2, nrElementeVector2);

    char* string1;
    char string2[50];

    string1 = citesteNume();
    cout << endl << "Hello " << string1;
    //delete[]string1; /*THIS IS NOT ALLOWED HERE*/
    citesteNume(string2);
    cout << endl << "Hello " << string2;

    vector1 = adaugaElementNou(nrElementeVector1, 99);
    afisareVector(vector1, nrElementeVector1+1);
    //delete[]vector1;
    adaugaElementNou(&vector1, &nrElementeVector1, 55);
    afisareVector(vector1, nrElementeVector1+1);
    //delete[]vector1;
    vector1 = adaugaElementNou(&nrElementeVector1, 77);
    afisareVector(vector1, nrElementeVector1+1);
    //delete[]vector1;

    //YOU CAN ADD NEW INSTRUCTIONS HERE
    // ...

    delete[] vector1; //I`ve tried to use delete here because I didn`t knew what else i should do, but I know that it makes no sense(and it`s not working);
    delete[] string1;

    //THE FOLLOWING CODE CHECKS IF THERE ARE ANY MEMORYLEAKS
    _CrtSetReportMode(_CRT_WARN, _CRTDBG_MODE_FILE);
    _CrtSetReportFile(_CRT_WARN, _CRTDBG_FILE_STDOUT);
    _CrtSetReportMode(_CRT_ERROR, _CRTDBG_MODE_FILE);
    _CrtSetReportFile(_CRT_ERROR, _CRTDBG_FILE_STDOUT);
    _CrtSetReportMode(_CRT_ASSERT, _CRTDBG_MODE_FILE);
    _CrtSetReportFile(_CRT_ASSERT, _CRTDBG_FILE_STDOUT);
    _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();

    //YOU CAN'T MODIFY THE FOLLOWING CODE
    vector1 = NULL;
    string1 = NULL;
    cout << endl << "In this moment there are no memory-leaks!";
}
```

Comment: Does this task allow to modify the behavior (expected output) of the program in order to get rid of memory leaks?

Comment: This homework assignment was apparently created by someone who learnt C++ about 20 years ago and has never bothered to update his knowledge.

Comment: I think I know what to do with `delete[]vector1`. I'm going to try and my hack tell you if I succeed.

Comment: Are you allowed to change inside `afisareVector` ?

Comment: @JSF yes i am. i`ve tried to delete memory inside afisareVector but i`m using the same method for the static array so i`m getting an error.(i`m not allowed to use another method for the static array).

Comment: The easiest option would be to not use `new` and `delete` at all. If you really really need to, then you should wait until you really really know how to handle them.

Comment: @AlexChihaia I found a way to solve this. Read [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33462311/5420829)

Comment: @juanchopanza it's not that I don't know how to handle them. The problem is the way i have to do it in this example(assigment) because I don't have "free hand" to do it as I would normally do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For string1 it's simple, you can just:

```
delete[] string1;
```

And this is what I think you are supposed to do deal with vector1:

```
void afisareVector(int* vector, int noElements) {
    cout << endl << "Vector:" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < noElements; i++)
        cout << vector[i] << " ";

    // A very dirty hack, PLEASE **NEVER** USE IT.
    static int callIndex = 0;
    if(callIndex != 1 && callIndex != 6)
        delete[] vector;
    ++callIndex;
}
```

valgrind summary:

```
==20937== HEAP SUMMARY:
==20937==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==20937==   total heap usage: 9 allocs, 9 frees, 144 bytes allocated
==20937== 
==20937== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==20937== 
==20937== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==20937== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Edit: I changed my mind. The example above is what you can do and this is what you are supposed to do:
Note #1: this hack feels even dirtier to me.
Note #2: In order to compile it, I had to remove all Microsoft-specific stuff and perform a leak checking with the valgrind.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;

/*YOU CAN'T ADD NEW METHODS*/
/*YOU CAN ONLY MODIFY THE BODY OF THE METHODS*/

//read array from the console - number of elements and the elements
int * readVectorVersion1(int * noElements) {
    static int vector1[50];
    for (int i = 0; i < *noElements; i++)
    {
        cout << endl << "Vector1[" << i + 1 << "]=";
        cin >> vector1[i];

    }
    return vector1;
}
//read array from the console - number of elements and the elements
void readVectorVersion2(int ** vector1, int* noElements) {
    static int vector [50];
    for (int i = 0; i < *noElements; i++)
    {
        cout << endl << "Vector1[" << i + 1 << "]=";
        cin >> vector[i];
    }
    *vector1 = vector;
}
//read array from the console - number of elements and the elements
void readVectorVersion3(int *& vector1, int& noElements) {
    static int vector [50];
    for (int i = 0; i < noElements; i++)
    {
        cout << endl << "Vector1[" << i + 1 << "]=";
        cin >> vector[i];
    }
    vector1 = vector;
}

//read array from the console - number of elements and the elements
int * readVectorVersion4(int& noElements) {
    static int vector1 [50];
    for (int i = 0; i < noElements; i++)
    {
        cout << endl << "Vector1[" << i + 1 << "]=";
        cin >> vector1[i];
    }
    return vector1;
}

//read static array from the console - number of elements and the elements
void readStaticVector(int vector[], int * noElements) {
    for (int i = 0; i < *noElements; i++)
    {
        cout << endl << "Vector1[" << i + 1 << "]=";
        cin >> vector[i];
    }
}

//print the elements of the array
void afisareVector(int* vector, int noElements) {
    cout << endl << "Vector:" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < noElements; i++)
        cout << vector[i] << " ";
}


//read a name from the console
char* citesteNume() {
    char temp[200];
    char * nume;
    cout << endl << "Your name:";
    cin >> temp;
    nume = new char[strlen(temp) + 1];
    strcpy(nume, temp);

    return nume;
}

//read a name from the console
void citesteNume(char* nume) {


    cout << endl << "Your name:";
    cin >> nume;


}
//METHODS THAT ADDS AN ELEMENT (THAT IS GIVEN) TO AN EXISTING ARRAY
//FIRST
void adaugaElementNou(int** vector, int* noElemente, int elementNou) {
    static int vector1 [50];
    for (int i = 0; i < *noElemente; i++)
        vector1[i] = i;

    vector1[*noElemente] = elementNou;
    *vector = vector1;
}
//SECOND
int * adaugaElementNou(int& noElemente, int elementNou) {
    static int vector [50];
    for (int i = 0; i < noElemente; i++)
        vector[i] = i;
    vector[noElemente] = elementNou;
    return vector;
}
//THIRD
int * adaugaElementNou(int* noElemente, int elementNou) {
    static int vector [50];
    for (int i = 0; i < *noElemente; i++)
        vector[i] = i;
    vector[*noElemente] = elementNou;
    return vector;
}



//THE PROGRAM MUST RUN AND NOT GENERATE ANY ERRORS OR MEMORY-LEAKS
int main() {
    //YOU CAN'T ADD NEW VARIABLES

    int * vector1;
    int vector2[50];
    int nrElementeVector1=3;
    int nrElementeVector2=3;

    //YOU CAN ADD NEW INSTRUCTIONS
    for (int i = 0; i < nrElementeVector2; i++)
        vector2[i] = i;
    vector1 = vector2;
    //YOU CAN'T MODIFY THE FOLLOWING CODE

    afisareVector(vector1, nrElementeVector1);
    afisareVector(vector2, nrElementeVector2);
    vector1 = readVectorVersion1(&nrElementeVector1);
    afisareVector(vector1, nrElementeVector1);
    readVectorVersion2(&vector1, &nrElementeVector1);
    afisareVector(vector1, nrElementeVector1);
    readVectorVersion3(vector1, nrElementeVector1);
    afisareVector(vector1, nrElementeVector1);
    vector1 = readVectorVersion4(nrElementeVector1);
    afisareVector(vector1, nrElementeVector1);
    readStaticVector(vector2, &nrElementeVector2);
    afisareVector(vector2, nrElementeVector2);

    char* string1;
    char string2[50];

    string1 = citesteNume();
    cout << endl << "Hello " << string1;
    citesteNume(string2);
    cout << endl << "Hello " << string2;

    vector1 = adaugaElementNou(nrElementeVector1, 99);
    afisareVector(vector1, nrElementeVector1+1);
    adaugaElementNou(&vector1, &nrElementeVector1, 55);
    afisareVector(vector1, nrElementeVector1+1);
    vector1 = adaugaElementNou(&nrElementeVector1, 77);
    afisareVector(vector1, nrElementeVector1+1);

    //YOU CAN ADD NEW INSTRUCTIONS HERE
    // ...

    delete[] string1;

    //YOU CAN'T MODIFY THE FOLLOWING CODE
    vector1 = NULL;
    string1 = NULL;
}
```

valgrind output:

```
==21224== HEAP SUMMARY:
==21224==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==21224==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 1 frees, 2 bytes allocated
==21224== 
==21224== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==21224== 
==21224== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==21224== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Edit: I came up with the 3rd (even dirtier) solution, but I'm too tired of all this hacking to write a complete version. Here is an example:

```
int * readVectorVersion1(int * noElements) {
    static int *vector1 = NULL;
    delete[] vector1;
    if (noElements < 0)
        return NULL;
    vector1 = new int[*noElements + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < *noElements; i++)
    {
        cout << endl << "Vector1[" << i + 1 << "]=";
        cin >> vector1[i];

    }
    return vector1;
}

// ...

int main() {
    // ...
    // Just before _CrtSetReportMode
    nrElementeVector1 = -1;
    readVectorVersion1(*nrElementeVector1);
    // ..
}
```

Comment: What does the if statement checks? Can you explain it to me? What are you using to display memory-leaks?

Comment: @AlexChihaia The 2nd time you call afisareVector and the 7th time you call afisareVector it can't free the memory, in all other places it has to do it. I just added a static counter to detect whether or not to call delete[]. P.S. I can't find a good link with an explanation of how static works.

Comment: @AlexChihaia If you want an explanation of how `static` works, I think [this link](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/programming_books/thinking_in_c++/Chapter10_002.html) would give you some clues. Also note: I changed my mind about what you are supposed to do (read updated answer).

Comment: I saw your second answer and It display no memory-leaks to me either. But this solution is working only on this example in particulary.Think about it. If I ask the user to give me the number of elements of the array and he wants the array to have 60 elements for example, it will be a problem.That`s why i`ve tried to allocate memory dynamically. You know what i mean?

Comment: It's my mistake that i've written there `int nrElementeVector1=3;`. In the initial code was `int nrElementeVector1;` and it was my job to ask the number of elements from the user but I did it like this to save time.

Comment: @AlexChihaia You can make those arrays really big or employ an even dirtier hack. The idea of the 3rd hack is to allocate the memory dynamically, store a static pointer inside the function and `delete[]` it when the size argument is `-1` (will require you to call every function with `-1` at the end of `main`).

Comment: @AlexChihaia BTW my first hack won't leak if you don't change the `main` (except removing the last `delete[] vector1`).

Comment: can you give me an example please for the "3rd hack"? For first function for example what should I write in the body of the func. and in the main func. Keep in mind that i'm allowed to modify only some parts of the code.

Comment: I have another ideea. Do you know if there is any library or function or something that allows me to check the way the memory is allocated. I mean i can modify the `afisareVector` method to delete the memory only for the arrays allocated with `new`.

Comment: Maybe something that checks if the pointer points to a memory that is on the heap or on the stack. What do you think?

Comment: @AlexChihaia AFAIK there's no such library. You can probably implement something highly dependent on your OS version, your compiler version and the phase of the Moon, but... BTW I added an example of the 3rd hack.

Comment: @AlexChihaia You can try comparing the address of an array passed to the `afisareVector` with the address of it's local variable, but it would probably be very OS, processor and compiler dependent. I heard that the stack grows towards the heap, but I doubt a program relying on this assumptions is guaranteed to work, unless it's made by a real expert.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say this task is impossible to accomplish. The line

```
vector1 = readVectorVersion1(&nrElementeVector1);
```

is executed when vector1 holds a dynamically allocated resource. Creating an unrecoverable leak at this point. The same goes for the following

```
readVectorVersion2(&vector1, &nrElementeVector1);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `vector1` pointer is overwritten in the code that you may not modify, so clearly it may not be the only pointer to dynamically allocated memory, or else it will leak and there is nothing you can do to stop that, within the restraints of your assignment.

So, let's explore the possibility of using a static object to hold the pointer. I'll use `std::vector` for simplicity, but you can use a static pointer to dynamic memory if you want to. In that case you'll need to manage the memory manually.

```
int * readVectorVersion1(int * noElements) {
    static std::vector<int> vector1;
    vector1.resize(*noElements);

    // initialize the way you want to

    return vector1.data();
    // return &vector1[0]; // use this if you use older version of c++ than c++11
}
```

And there you go. The memory will be deallocated when static objects are destroyed. This of course does limit what you can do with the function. You can no longer allocate two separate arrays because subsequent calls will use the same vector. But it's not needed for this assignment, so I guess this is what your instructor is asking for.

Comment: Ok. I wrote this code and I still have memory-leaks(or at least this is the output). When i use "delete [] vector1" in main the program runs but than i`m getting an error. What i am doing wrong?
THIS IS THE CODE:

Comment: `#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int * readVectorVersion1(int * noElements) {
 
 static vector<int> vector1;
 vector1.resize(*noElements);
 unsigned int i;
 // initialize the way you want to
 for (i = 0; i < vector1.size(); i++)
 {
  cout << endl << "Vector1[" << i + 1 << "]=";
  cin >> vector1[i];
}
  return &vector1[0];
}
void afisareVector(int* vector, int noElements) {
 cout << endl << "Vector:" << endl;
 for (int i = 0; i < noElements; i++)
  cout << vector[i] << " ";
}`

Comment: `void main(){

 int *vector1;
 int nrElem = 4;
 vector1 = readVectorVersion1(&nrElem);
 afisareVector(vector1,nrElem);

 //delete [] vector1;
 _CrtSetReportMode(_CRT_WARN, _CRTDBG_MODE_FILE);
 _CrtSetReportFile(_CRT_WARN, _CRTDBG_FILE_STDOUT);
 _CrtSetReportMode(_CRT_ERROR, _CRTDBG_MODE_FILE);
 _CrtSetReportFile(_CRT_ERROR, _CRTDBG_FILE_STDOUT);
 _CrtSetReportMode(_CRT_ASSERT, _CRTDBG_MODE_FILE);
 _CrtSetReportFile(_CRT_ASSERT, _CRTDBG_FILE_STDOUT);
 _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();


}`

Comment: "When i use "delete [] vector1" in main the program runs but than i`m getting an error" Well of course you are. You may not delete the memory owned by the vector.

Comment: Ok but if i don`t do this I have memory leaks. What should I do?

Comment: @AlexChihaia do you have any calls to `new` that don't have  a matching `delete`? Get rid of those.

Comment: Although your approach won't produce any actual memory leaks, the code that checks for leaks is located at the end of the `main` function and executes before those static vectors get destroyed. So it'll think that the memory is leaked even though it's not. P.S. I never used this MS tool so may be I  misunderstand how it works.

Comment: @АндрейБеньковский good point. I didn't pay attention to the way the leaks are detected. I haven't used it either, but I think you may be right that this method will result in a false positive with static objects owning dynamic memory. It seems that OP's assignment is impossible short of very kludgy hacks like your solution.